# String sanitization to escape special characters

Tags: swift3

Hi I would like to build a function which will replace all the special character ie: * & ! @ # $ % with "//(with whatever the match will be)

so I string like "1*234@" will become 1//*/234//@"

is there a replace function in swift to do that?

Comment: Yes, there is really an implementation of regular expressions. Which is what you should probably use. See `NSRegularExpression`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String.replacingOccurrences which can be used like so:

```
    let replacements = ["!" : "-exclamation-", "." : "-period-"]
    var stringToModify = "hello! This is a string."
    replacements.keys.forEach { stringToModify = stringToModify.replacingOccurrences(of: $0, with: replacements[$0]!)}
    print(stringToModify)
```

output: **hello -exclamation-  This is a string -period-**

There is also an overload with more options, incase you want to do stuff like case insensitive compare.  https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsstring/1416484-replacingoccurrences